# How to save input as a variable that can be accessed in other files

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to save someones input as a variable then access it from another file?

Ex. Someone types in `John` and it sets it as a var (x) in `one.js`. Then on another html file in another folder a button calls the function `alert(x)`

Comment: That sounds like you want a global variable. Using globals isn't a good practice though, perhaps think of another way to organize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to do this.

File 1

```
localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");
```

File 2

```
alert(localStorage.getItem("foo"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 API for [Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)